# How thread lock works when modifying an object item in a thread safe object collection through reference

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, memorycache

I've a thread safe object  collection, for e.g c#  MemoryCache. As we know, the operations like adding, updating and removing item in this collection is safe. But if I update properties of an object item in the collection through reference , firstly, would it be thread safe? how the synchronization works? would it be locked each line of property update?

```
class MyClass
{
     public int Val1 { get; set; }
     public int Val2 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    public static MemoryCache MyCache = new MemoryCache("test");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        MyCache.Add("1", new MyClass() {Val1 = 0, Val2 = 0}, new CacheItemPolicy());

        new Thread(() => {

            MyClass item = (MyClass)MyCache["1"];                
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                item.Val1 =  item.Val1 + i;
            }

        }).Start();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            MyClass item = (MyClass)MyCache["1"];
            for (int i = 100000; i < 200000; i++)
            {
                item.Val1 =  item.Val1 + i;
            }
        }).Start();
```

any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: You already have the code to test it.  What happened when you ran it?

Comment: The result looks all thread safe. But I read in few blogs it is not, so just want to check more comments.

Comment: So you knew the answer to your question before you asked it?  Then why did you bother asking the question if you already knew the answer?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel He states that he did his research, found out that it wasn't safe, assumed it was safe despite being told that it wasn't, asked again, and was told what he had already found before, that it's not safe.

Answer (score 2):

> But if I update properties of an object item in the collection through
>   reference , firstly, would it be thread safe?

No.

> how the synchronization works?

There will be no synchronization write reading/writing the property.

> would it be locked each line of property update?

No.

Comment: Thanks dugas, but when I ran the test code (above), it gives a thread safe result. How that would be?

Comment: @JustinMathew How were you validating the result?

Comment: There are several reasons you could have appeared to get a correct result (for example a single core cpu, cpu architecture,  memory model, etc...). Your example is absolutely not thread safe.

Comment: @Servy - I'm not sure that my test is proper or not, what I did, I've created three threads to do a sum of one property (Val1) and get the right sum after execution. Could you tell me ? how I can prove it's not thread safe.